# LinkedIn API access to Compliance solution

Tags: linkedin-api

Goodmorning,

I’ve been looking into the documentation for the linkedin API.
I'm interested in the compliance solution, in particular the following APIs:

- Organization Lookup API
- Company Search API
- Organization Access Control API
- Some APIs of the People integration

I didn't understand if the compliance solution is accessible or not and if I should apply for it.

I've posted this question on the microsoft docs Q&A section and they told me to post it here where the linkedin API team can help me.

Thank you,
Giovanni.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is not possible to request access to the Compliance API, see here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#compliance-closed

I realized that LinkedIn from the service voyager use
link is related to Voyager

https://linkedin.api-docs.io/v1.0/messaging/RMTx5GgWKsMivwQ7m

But sending messages is not mentioned in this document

ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ

You should go to this link and register a ticket and say that you want to use this access

https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Company/Organization Name

Brief Summary of what the organization does.

Precise use case for Compliance APIs

List of Compliance APIs that you intend to use for your Compliance-related activities.

Complete the information for the LinkedIn development team to review